# Javascript templates in Django

Tags: javascript, django, templates, jquery-file-upload

My purpose is really simple. I want to re-produce the exact same demo from
[this page](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html)
in my Django project, so I copied the ***index.html*** file to my project.

At the end of the code, there are some Javascript template syntaxes; for example, `{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}`

and Django complains about that: `'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) {`

I think the reason is because Django also uses the same syntax for templates, but I don't quite know how to fix it. Does anyone know how to fix the problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django provides the `{% verbatim %}` tag. You can use it to ignore the template tokens (`{{ {% %} }}`) in a fragment of the template.

Example:

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% verbatim %}
    // your template here
{% endverbatim %}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly! By the way, do you know any references that I can use to integrate the JQuery-File-Upload plugin to my project? I can't really find any good ones for Django. Most of them are outdated. The version I'm using is Django 1.6.5.